# Find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\int\limits_{x^2}^{2x} t^4 \cdot e^{t^2} \,\, dt}{e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Find $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\int\limits_{x^2}^{2x} t^4 \cdot e^{t^2} \, dt}{\displaystyle e^x-1-x-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{4!}}$$

So lets say that $F' = t^4 \cdot e^{t^2}$

Now we can see that we can use L'Hospital rule because it is $\frac{0}{0}$

So when we apply we have that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(F(2x) - F(x^2))'}{\left(\dfrac{x^5}{5!} + o(x^5)\right)'} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{16x^4 \cdot (1+4x^2+o(x^2)) - x^8e^{x^4}}{\dfrac{x^4}{4!} + o(x^4)} = 256$$

But the answer is 768. Where is the mistake?

And next question: Can I always define such $F$ and just substitute limits of integration (like I have done above) and then use L'Hospital rule (ofc when condition for using the rule are fulfilled)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(F(2x)-F(x^2))'=2f(x)-2xf(x)$. This correction to your calculations gives $2\cdot16\cdot4!=768$.

Certainly it means that the answer to your second question must include a correction of the formula:
$$
\left(\int_{d(x)}^{g(x)}f(t)\,dt\right)'=F'(g(x))g'(x)-F'(d(x))d'(x).
$$

Comment: I have completely forgot about using there the chain rule... Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $F(2x)-F(x^2)$ is $2F'(2x)-2xF'(x^2)$ (by the chain rule), so the numerator after L'Hopital's is actually $32x^4$ plus higher terms.  So we have the limit being $32(4!) = 32 \cdot 24 = 768$.